# jqm iscrollview scroller "min-height" to high

Tags: jquery-mobile, uiscrollview

I have an jqm page with an header and an div block who will be always visible. After this block I have added a listview in an new div and enabled iscroll via `data-iscroll=""`.

If it has to scroll, the iscroll-div gets an to high height value. Some Content is not Visible and Scrollable (see Screenshot the Red Circle).

[image]

My shorted Code is following:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageId">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        {title}
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="details-header">
            <img src="{url}" />
            {some text}
        </div>
        <div data-iscroll="">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p style="white-space:normal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[..]</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p style="white-space:normal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[..]</p>
            </li>
            [...]
        </ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that the min-height is calculated by the device-height - header-height. Is there a way to to recalculate the iscroll divs height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution: `data-iscroll-fixed=""` for containers outside the `data-iscroll` element do the job.